# How Can I Put Something in a RO FS (Linux Debian) if it will Not Boot?

Tags: debian, boot, firmware, bootable, readonly

I have a Debian Linux install that boots but only to a specific point...

The booting stops at a firmware error. My system seems to be RO and when I boot into a "safe mode," to alter the set up to handle firmware-realtek for my Ethernet Port in /lib/firmware, I cannot do anything since it is RO.

Is there a way to place and save files, .fw files, so that the system accepts them and I can finally boot?

rtl_nic/rtl8168-2.fw is the file in question that is preventing my Ethernet Port from working on this model of motherboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to manually remount the system to read/write:

```
# mount / -oremount,rw
```

After this your root filesystem will be mounted read/write so you can modify files.

Normally this step is performed at the appropriate point when the system progresses from starting with its initial setup and system checks to enabling a full multi-user environment, but during safe mode it doesn't -- because it's meant to be **safe** mode, to allow you to run checks before it does anything that might affect the system and/or trigger whatever happened that made you feel it was necessary to boot into safe mode in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an answer quick enough or by any research performed. I booted another image to the machine in question. For some reason, it booted w/out error this time.

I see that firmware-realtek is not even a thing but that it is referenced in many places online.

Comment: [Yes it is](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/firmware-realtek). `apt search firmware-realtek` returns `firmware-realtek/stable,stable,now 20210315-3 all [installed] ... Binary firmware for Realtek wired/wifi/BT adapters`. You need to have the `non-free` repo in your `/etc/sources.list` to `apt install` it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Peregrino69 , thank you. I misunderstood how to attain the firmware-realtek installs.

Comment: @Community , I do not know what happened and to say that I am completely sure of what happened will be false. I am sorry.